# is it possible to do the Kri'ah at the moment of the death, and not at the funeral?

Tags: death, mourning-aveilus

is it possible to do the Kri'ah at the exact moment of the death, and not only at the funeral?

Comment: It's not just possible. It's obligatory!

Comment: Thank you!! So does it mean you do it twice? At the moment of the death + at the moment of the funeral?

Comment: See https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/67172/759 For parents, you tear anything you wear from moment of death until after Shiva. In all other cases you just tear once.

Comment: I can think of 2 reasons as to why tearing is done at the funeral - 1) People don't know what to do until a rabbi instructs them. The 1st time they see the rabbi is usually at the funeral. 2) As in my case, the person is extremely busy arranging the burial, speaking to the funeral home, notifying other close family members, making travel plans, etc. - they forget.